# How to add tags when uploading files with Laravel using an S3 disk?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3

When using the filesystem S3 (S3 Disk or S3 Adapter) within Laravel, how do you add S3 tags?

For example, given the following upload, how is the tag `foo=bar` added to the uploaded file?

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('file.txt', 'hello', 'private');
```

Answer (score 4):

This took some digging, so wanted to document it here:

```php
Storage::disk('s3')->put('file.txt', 'hello', [
    'Tagging' => 'foo=bar
    'visibility' => 'private',
]);
```

You need to append the visibility attribute manually if you want to maintain what was there prior to updating the config from a string to an object.

Explanation notes:

- Laravel has a filesystem adapter that does a string check on the config, if it is a string, it wraps it in an object with a visibility key
- This constructed config object is passed into the flysystem (https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem)
- "Tagging" is the syntax that S3 expects (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject - see also the tagging section)
- Multiple tags can be done with a url query set `dog=good&cat=bad` (from S3 docs: "The tag-set must be encoded as URL Query parameters")